# Python fit uniform distribution

Tags: python, scipy, distribution

I'm trying to fit a set of data with uniform distribution. This is what I have tried based on normal distribution fitting.  I'm not sure whether this implementation is correct or not? Can you please advise.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import uniform
mu, std = uniform.fit(data)


plt.hist(data, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='#6495ED')


xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = uniform.pdf(x, mu, std)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
title = "Fit results: mu = %.2f,  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)
plt.title("Uniform Fitting")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's generally right, once you fix the name errors (I assume `logods` and `data` are meant to be the same). Note that the parameters of the `uniform` distribution are general location and scale parameters (specifically, the lower boundary and width, respectively) and should not be named `mu` and `std`, which are specific to the normal distribution. But that doesn't affect the correctness of the code, just the understandability.

Answer (score 0):

I would use OpenTURNS's `UniformFactory`: the `build` method returns a distribution which has a `drawPDF` method.

```
import openturns as ot
data = [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6., 7., 8.]
sample = ot.Sample(data,1)
distribution = ot.UniformFactory().build(sample)
distribution.drawPDF()
```

This produces:

[image: Uniform distribution]